# erros com ssl na urllib3

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

eu criei um keygen para o hack the box (nada de ilegal aqui, apenas automatização), porem na tentativa de rodar o código no MacOs recebi o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 362, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 384, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "htb_keygen.py", line 6, in <module>
    r = http.request("POST", "https://www.hackthebox.eu/api/invite/generate")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 79, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 171, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 336, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 754, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 754, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 754, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.hackthebox.eu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/invite/generate (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

ou mais resumidamente:

```
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.hackthebox.eu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/invite/generate (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

em sites sem ssl, codigos com a urllib3 rodaram sem problemas no meu mac, porem todos os sites com ssl ocorrem esse erro

segue o codigo para que possa testar em sua maquina:

```
import base64
import urllib3
import json
urllib3.disable_warnings()
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request("POST", "https://www.hackthebox.eu/api/invite/generate")
code = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
key = code['data']
crypt = key['code']
base64_bytes = crypt.encode('ascii')
message_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_bytes)
keygenerated = message_bytes.decode('ascii')
print(f'aqui esta a sua chave: {keygenerated}')
```

ja testei: rodar em outra maquina com sistema operacional diferente(funcionou)